# Some insights in quotient topologies

Tags: general-topology, quotient-spaces

One of Munkres' exercises tasks us to consider the following quotient space $\mathbb{R}^2/\sim$ in $\mathbb{R}^2$ given by the following equivalence relationship:
$$(x,y)\sim(a,b)\iff x^2 + y^2 = a^2 + b^2$$

If one's to consider $\mathbb{R}^2/\sim$ graphically, it's composed by all the circles whose center is at $(0,0)$. The exercise asks: "this quotient space is homeomorphic to a well-known space, which is it?". I incline to think that we can map a circle to its radius so, for me, $$\mathbb{R}^2/_\sim \; \simeq \; [0,\infty)$$
For this, I consider $f\colon [0,\infty) \to \mathbb{R}^2/\sim$ with $r\mapsto [(0,r)]$ (i.e. the circle with radius $r$). I must prove that $f$ is an homeomorphism, but I'm unable to grasp how the open sets in the quotient topology look like. **Would anyone give me some insight on how these open sets look like and how would I work with them?**

Comment: I haven't thought about it too much, but it seems like open sets might be open annuli?

Comment: I guess: the map of $(a,b)$ would be all circles with radius $r$ such that $a<r<b$. But how would I work with 'em?

Comment: You could consider the norm map $N:\Bbb R^2\to[0,\infty),\, (x,y)\mapsto \sqrt{x^2+y^2}$. This map is continuous and surjective, and $N(x,y)=N(a,b)$ if and only if $(x,y)\sim(a,b)$, which implies that there is a continuous bijection $\tilde N: \Bbb R^2/{\sim} \to [0,\infty)$. If you can show that $N$ is an open map, then you can conclude that $\tilde N$ is a homeomorphism.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a set $U\in X/{\sim}$ to be open, you require that the union of the equivalence classes $$\bigcup_{[x]\in U}[x]$$ be open in $X$.

*What they look like.* So in this case, you require that the union of the equivalence classes be an open subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$ which, as AJ Stas mentions in the comments, are open annuli.

*How to work with them.* Prove that the annuli $$\{[(x,y)]\in\mathbb{R}^2\;\colon\;a<x^2+y^2<b\},\quad a<b$$
form a basis of the topology on $\mathbb{R}^2/{\sim}$; and that their pre-images under (your) $f$ are open intervals $(a,b)\in[0,\infty)$, and you have shown $f$ is continuous.

Answer (score 1):

HINT: From the standpoint of intuition it may be easiest to work with polar coordinates. Every point of $\Bbb R^2$ has a unique representation in polar coordinates $\langle r,\theta\rangle$ such that $r\ge 0$ and $0\le\theta<2\pi$; now let $h(\langle r,\theta\rangle)=r$.